# Vaadin maven-project stopped builds normally

Tags: maven, gwt, vaadin

CVS rollbacks will not help. Builds failing on local machines and on jenkins server.
I use multimodule archetype (vaadin-archetype-application-multimodule, https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes)

Steps to buid:
mvn clean install (work)
mvn project-production/pom.xml -Pproduction package (crash)
Vaadin version: 7.4.0

Error message:

> [DEBUG] Execute command : C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -classpath
>   C:\Users\vbeglyanin\IdeaProjects\SberWeb\sber-web-production\target\classes;
>   ... project specific stuff ...
>   C:\Users\vbeglyanin.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlets\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-servlets-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\vbeglyanin.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-client\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-client-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\vbeglyanin.m2\repository\ant\ant-launcher\1.6.5\ant-launcher-1.6.5.jar
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war
>   C:\Users\vbeglyanin\IdeaProjects\SberWeb\sber-web-production\target\sber-web\VAADIN\widgetsets
>   -localWorkers 4 -strict -XfragmentCount -1 -gen C:\Users\vbeglyanin\IdeaProjects\SberWeb\sber-web-production\target.generated
>   ru.tsc.crs.web.MyAppWidgetset
>   [ERROR] Unknown argument: -XfragmentCount
>   [ERROR] Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0
>   ... (list available arguments)

Empty vaadin project created from archetype builds normally.
.pom`s files not modified except add dependencies and repositories, but that was before there was a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/VRjRb-nAWYQ) this happens, when you are using a different gwt version than expected. From your log we can see that you are using 2.3.0, the mailing list says you need at least 2.5.1.

You have probably added a new dependency which uses an older version of gwt than the archetype expects.

Run `mvn -f project-production/pom.xml -Pproduction dependency:tree -Dverbose` and grep for `gwt`.

Then look for something like

```
\- (com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.5.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.3.0)
```

then you can see which dependency causes the conflict.